# unable to connect to DB using sqlplus: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: linux, sqlplus, oracle12c, tns

I'm trying to connect to connect to DB through `sqlplus` from one of the Linux servers, but getting below error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu May 16 15:49:15 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:
```

I re-installed `oracle` client in my server, hoping it'll resolve the issue,but no luck!

Usage:

```
$>sqlplus user_name/passwd@SID
```

Any help is most welcome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when you're trying to connect to a database whose alias isn't contained in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. For example:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@does_not_exist
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

So, check what's written in TNSNAMES.ORA you use.

---

Note that mostly every Oracle software product you install contains its own TNSNAMES.ORA file. If that's your situation as well, I'd suggest you to:

- create a directory on your hard disk (for example, c:\oralib)
- put one of TNSNAMES.ORA files in there
- copy/paste all databases you're accessing into that file
- create environment variable named TNS_ADMIN which will point to that directory
- doing so, every Oracle product will look only at that TNSNAMES.ORA file
- furthermore, it means that you'll have to maintain only one copy of the file, not all of them